# How to convert column into row with header sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

[image: i have a this type of table]

Note : i need the record like this

```
Scode value
BR     10
DL      7
```

Comment: I'd consider UNION ALL.

Comment: @Rajeshkr . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: @Rajeshkr use pivot

Comment: pivot is not working

Comment: What have you tried? Pivot with dynamic columns?

Comment: ;WITH CTE
AS
  
  (
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT top 1 AP,BR,DL,HP,KL,MH,PY,RJ,TG,TR,UP,[AS],GJ,JH,MP,PB,WB,JK,UT,GA,CG,HR,OD,TN,KA,Chandigarh,AN 
  FROM TAB) T
  UNPIVOT ( Value FOR N IN (AP,BR,DL,HP,KL,MH,PY,RJ,TG,TR,UP,[AS],GJ,JH,MP,PB,WB,JK,UT,GA,CG,HR,OD,TN,KA,CH,AN))P
  )
 SELECT Value AS Total FROM CTE

Comment: make it dynamic.

Comment: @Rajeshkr Please check my answer and accept it if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `union all`:

```
select 'br', br from t union all
select 'dl', dl from t union all
select 'AP', ap from t;
```

In a database that supports lateral joins, I would recommend something like this:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('br', br), ('dl', dl), ('AP', ap)
     ) v(col, val);
```

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: @Rajeshkr . . . Then use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this query, it is dynamic and working.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
    [br] [int] NULL,
    [dl] [int] NULL,
    [ap] [int] NULL,
    [hp] int null,
    [kl] int null,
    [mh] int null,
    [py] int null
)

insert into temp values(10,7,7,7,8,8,0)

--Drop Table if exists #temp2
--drop table if exists #temp

create table #temp2(id int identity primary key,Scode varchar(10),value int)
declare @col varchar(max),@count int,@intcount int=1,@strquery varchar(max),@id int

select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by column_id) as RN,name into #temp from sys.columns where object_id=OBJECT_ID('temp')

select @count=count(1) from #temp
while(@intcount<=@count)
begin
set @strquery=''
set @col=''
set @id=0
    select @col=name from #temp where RN=@intcount

    set @strquery='select '+@col+' from temp'

    insert into #temp2(value)
    exec(@strquery)
    select @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    update  #temp2 set [Scode]=@col where id=@id

    set @intcount=@intcount+1

end
select * from temp
select Scode,value from #temp2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go on this link and See the simple solution my problem is Solve.
https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/5259227/Convert-column-into-row-with-header-in-SQL#answer1

Answer (score 0):

```
You could also use CROSS APPLY with UNION ALL to convert the columns:


 select id, br,
 dl,
  ap
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'br', Indicator1 union all
  select 'dl', Indicator2 union all
  select 'ap', Indicator3
) c (indicatorname, indicatorvalue);
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide explanation why this is the preferred solution as we want to educate not just serve ready made code, Thanks.